# Value is splited into half before submission

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using text box to update User record, it Submits half name to database e.g. if Name is 'John Mathew' then it only submits 'John'. EVen i checked in deugging that value being sent from Textbox to action is complete but submitted half, why ? i noticed, my textbox is binded to EmplName field in database and it picks half name from there, in value it shows half name that's why it submit half name why ?

this line :

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult InsertEmployeeEditedDetail(String EmpName, String DeptID, String ShiftId, String EntryDate, String Salary, String Email, bool Approval)
        {
            int? EmplId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpEdit"]);
            var UpdateRec = DataContext.UpdateEmployeeDetails_Sp(EmplId, EmpName, DeptID, ShiftId, EntryDate, Salary, Email, Approval);
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
@model IEnumerable<GetEmployeeEditDetails_SpResult>

@{
    var Item = Model.FirstOrDefault();
 }

<style type="text/css">

</style>
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertEmployeeEditedDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <label id="lblName" class="editEmp_label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" value= @Item.EmplName  name="EmpName" placeholder="Update Name" />
  <br />
  <label id="lblDept" class="editEmp_label">Department</label>
  @Html.DropDownList("DeptID", @Item.DeptName)
  <br />
  <label id="lblShift" class="editEmp_label">Shift</label>
  @Html.DropDownList("ShiftId", @Item.ShiftName)
  <br />
  <label id="lblEntryDate" class="TxtBoxFrom editEmp_label">Entry Date</label>
  <input type="text" value= @Item.EntryDate class="TxtBoxTo" name="EntryDate" placeholder="Update Date"  />
  <br />
  <label id="lblSalary" class="editEmp_label">Salary</label>
  <input type="text" value= @Item.BasicSalary  name="Salary" placeholder="Update Salary"   />
  <br />
  <label id="lblEmail" class="editEmp_label">Email</label>
  <input type="text" value= @Item.EmailAdd  name="Email" placeholder="Update Email"   />
  <br />
  <label id="lblApproved" class="editEmp_label">Overtime Approval</label>
  @Html.CheckBox("Approval", @Convert.ToBoolean( @Item.OvertimeApproved))
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="button_AdminPanel" style="width:75px" name="btnSubmit">Update</button>  

}
```

Store Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmployeeDetails_Sp]
    @Emplid int,
    @EmplName varchar(40),
    @DeptId char(36),
    @ShiftId char(40),
    @EntryDate char(10),
    @Salary varchar(50),
    @EmailAdd varchar(50),
    @OvertimeApproval bit


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Update HrEmployee 
    Set EmplName = @EmplName, EntryDate=@EntryDate, BasicSalary=@Salary, 
                   EmailAdd=@EmailAdd, OvertimeApproved= @OvertimeApproval, 
                   DeptID=@DeptId, ShiftID=@ShiftId
                   where EmplID =@Emplid

END
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear:  is this name-splitting something you WANT to have happen that ISN'T, or something that IS happening that you DON'T want?

Comment: I want to submit full name to database not splitted, 

E.g. want to submit Mathew Jackson but it submits Mathew only, why ?

Comment: What is `EmplName` defined as in the database?  How long is it?

Comment: i noticed another thing, my text box is binded to EmplName field in database and it picks half name from there, 

this line :   <input type="text" value= @Item.EmplName  name="EmpName" placeholder="Update Name" />

Comment: How do you know that the name is being split or truncated?  Have you checked the database record, or is this based on the appearance of the screen after the submission?

Comment: Assuming that the form displays forename and surname ok, as far as I can see your code is correct - there is nothing that can split the name in two, except perhaps a database trigger

Comment: @NeilThompson sir in short. My Textbox is binded to database field, EmplName. It was supposed to show name in textbox , it does but doesn't show full name

Comment: Could the last name just be hidden from view by the length of the textbox?  If you put your cursor in the textbox and scroll with the arrow key to the end of the text, does the last name appear?

Comment: enclose value attribute value in double quots value="@Item.EmplName".  If there is space in the name, Last name (after space) becomes attribute to the input control which is not visible and can't be sent back

Comment: @Nps good spot, surely that's the answer?

Comment: @Nps amazing dude, Done, please post it as an answer so i could mark an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose value attribute value in double quots value="@Item.EmplName". If there is space in the name, Last name (after space) becomes attribute to the input control which is not visible and can't be sent back.

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if you use `@Html.TextBoxFor()`,this would handle binding as well instead of explicitely setting the textbox value using 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Given that all your code looks reasonable enough, I can only think of a few possibilities:

1. Perhaps the code that calls your stored procedure from the DataContext has the parameter length for `EmplName` as something much shorter.
2. Perhaps the database table has a trigger that is manipulating that column's value.
3. Perhaps something is going wrong - like an output parameter that is too short - when you retrieve the data from the database and display it.